# Why can't I get this VERY simple AngularJS code to work?

Tags: angularjs

This whole app should consist of an h1 element that says 'Adrian' and a paragraph that says 'He lives in Orlando'. I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. BTW, I already know that this isn't the best design pattern for Angular, but I just wanted something quick to get my feet wet with the framework.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Angular Demo</title>
            <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div ng-controller="MyController">
                <h1>{{person.firstName}}</h1>
                <p>He lives in {{person.city}}</p>
            </div>

            <script>
                function MyController($scope) {
                    $scope.person = {
                        'firstName': 'Adrian',
                        'city': 'Orlando'
                    }
                }
            </script>
        </body>

</html>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_controllers.asp A controller has to be assigned to a module.

Answer (score 2):

You are not making Angular aware of your `MyController` function:

```
<!doctype html>
    <!-- tell Angular what module to use -->
    <html lang="en" ng-app="app">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Angular Demo</title>
            <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div ng-controller="MyController">
                <h1>{{person.firstName}}</h1>
                <p>He lives in {{person.city}}</p>
            </div>

            <script>
                angular
                    // Define our module
                    .module('app', [])
                    // Define our controller
                    .controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
                        $scope.person = {
                            'firstName': 'Adrian',
                            'city': 'Orlando'
                        }
                    });
            </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the only comment so far that's helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Get in the habit of assigning app names and controllers to the apps, here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/gfWh6fqWeni8s8M0iG1B?p=preview

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
                   $scope.person = {
                        'firstName': 'Adrian',
                        'city': 'Orlando'
                    }
});
</script>
```

I am not even trying to be a patronizing ass, but check the tutorial [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_controllers.asp) It will take you a couple of hours. Then head over to [Jenkov's](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/index.html) "complete" tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine. I believe your angular source file is the issue try switching it to a CDN src or double check your path

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sfwtfp35/2/

Comment: Useful. I am so used to assigning it, I just automatically assumed it was the issue. Cool that you checked.

Comment: Yeah apart from the other suggestions given to improve your code, CDNs are a great way to maintain your code but more importantly it reduces latency which provides a faster loading of your website.

Comment: This didn't work. Thanks for the reply though. Each reply I've read so far has either taught me something about Angular or reinforced a key concept.